# Why doesnt a migration update a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails and trying to understand the relationship between migrations and models. As far as I can tell the migration seems to only affect the datastore hence after I use scaffolding to create a resource, am I then responsible for keeping the model and migrations in sync? Are there any tools to assist in this?

Sorry if this is an obvious question, I'm still working my way through the docs.

Comment: What do you mean by `model and migrations in sync` ? You should add a new migration and start to use the new attributes on your model, not keep editing the existing migration (well, you can sometimes, but well...)

Comment: My confusion partly stems from the fact that using a scaffold to generate a resource adds attr_accessible to the model. I was surprised that creating a migration to add a new field did not update the model....

Comment: `attr_accessible` is the mass-assignment whitelist. Imagine if Rails automagically updated this for you when you added something like `admin` to the schema!

Comment: I had to go away and find out what mass-assignment was. I see the problem. While I understand that a scaffold generates a lot of boilerplate code, is the fact that it adds attr_accessible then "bad practice"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All migrations do is modify the database. Rails handles maintaining the sync between the model and the database.

You can have a `User` table that has `id`, `firs_name` and your class model might look like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

As you can see the model class is empty and you can still pretty much access methods on that class like this:

```
@user = User.new
@user.first_name = "Leo"
@user.save!
```

and it will know what to do with it.

Migrations are just files that allow you to modify the database in incremental steps while keeping a sane versioning on the database schema.

Of course, Rails will complain if you try to call things from your model that don't exist in the database or the `ActiveRecord::Base` parent class.

```
@user = User.new
@user.awesome
#=> undefined method `awesome` for #<User:some_object_id>
```

As for the migrations, you can have multiple migrations that affect one table. Your job is only to know what attributes you've added to a model. Rails will do the rest for you.

Comment: So to check I understand, the class model will never contain information about the fields defined via migrations and the principle source of schema information is schema.rb rather than the model files?

Comment: I guess in a way. The schema is just a representation of what has been written to the database so far by the migrations. Its in plain ruby or you can output it as SQL as well. What actually does the interaction between the model and the database is ActiveRecord::Base. Specifically if you do `SomeModel.new.method(:some_method).source_location` it points to where the method is defined and interestingly it points to `lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb`

Answer (score 0):

A general rule of thumb is that migrations are best suited for Data Definition - columns in table, their type, constraints etc. So no, you do not need to keep a migration in sync with your data.

If in the longer run, your data definition itself changes (new column or change in a column type), then just adda new migration specifying the same.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord models are driven, in general, from the database.  Any fields defined in the database will (generally) appear automatically as properties in the activerecord model bound to that table.

Altering the model will not change the schema (generally).  To alter the model, one would typically define a migration and run it into the database.

Note that nothing stops you defining additional properties on the model with attr_accessor etc, but these will not be persisted by ActiveRecord if there is no column in the schema to which they are bound.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken Leo's answer since he helped me to understand things better and if I had just got to the bottom of the page on migrations I might not have needed to ask : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#what-are-schema-files-for

The mentioned annotate_models gem also sound useful in helping improve awareness of the current structure of a class model without having to refer to the schema.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to revert the attr_accessor behavior and instead give a whitelist give a blacklist, you can do per model using this:

```
attr_accesible *atribute_names - %(attributes black list)
```